# CSV on server with access denied less secure than info in DB?

Tags: php, database, apache, csv

Security wise, is it enough to deny access to a folder container sensitive CSV files via Apache or is it much better to just have the data in a database?

The CSV/database files would be used to populating html tables per user per date.

I thought it would be simpler to organize by just uploading CSVs by date and user VS populating a complex database but I don't want to jeopardize security.

Comment: apache shouldn't be denying acess. if the files are sensitive, they shouldn't be inside the document root to begin with.

Comment: So if I allow admin to upload csv to outside webroot I can still popular HTML tables with a script and the data is just as secure if not more secure than if it were in a database?

Comment: sounds like data that should be in a db

Comment: @Dragon Why a db instead of outside document root?

Comment: faster and easier to maintain data in a db than a flat file

Comment: @Dragon the admin will have all their data in csv files per day. I'm thinking organize the many csvs outside document root and populate table on request with specified respective csv. If I do a db it will mean many uploads of csv to MySQL and if those csv columns change ill have a big headache on my hands maintaining the db. The only thing holding me back from csvs in folders is the security concern.